# React lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I have been doing react for a while and am familiar with some lifecycle methods but not so familiar with others

e.g. `didMount` is clearly for ajax requests or calling data from an api then loading it into the app

I think I have conquered `shouldComponentUpdate`, and have realised it is purely there for performance

but `static getDerivedStateFromProps` I cant really get my head around. is that for performance or does that add something else to the app?

and also `componentDidUpdate`, is this for performance again or where is a good example where I can use these?

clearly some methods are necessary to perform actions and actual requests. clearly some are there to improve performance etc. just would like to get some context around `didUpdate` and `getDerived`

thanks

Comment: Have you read https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html and https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html?

Comment: read the first, not the second. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can understand the lifecycle hooks in react through this blog  : https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle methods made to allow you to run code at particular times in the process.

**componentDidMount()** is invoked immediately after a component is inserted into the tree, we commonly use it to make API requests.

Using React Hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    makeApiRequest()
}, [])
```

**componentDidUpdate()** is invoked immediately after updating occurs (in the state or props). This method is not called for the initial render. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request

Using React Hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    doYourStuff()
})
```

> The difference between componentDidUpdate and the Hook above that the Hook will be called in the initial render also. There is no 100% alternative to the componentDidUpdate() method.

**componentWillUnmount()** is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions.

Using React Hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        cleanUp()
    }
})
```

**getDerivedStateFromProps()** is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

Read More -> [React Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)